# Where does jenkins mailer plugIn store SMTP server name

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-mailer-plugin

I am using Jenkins v 2.60.2 and the Jenkins Mailer plugin

When I configure jenkins and add an SMTP server name, where is this information persisted? Most jenkins info is stored as XML files in jenkins home, but I cannot seem to find this info anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but try file:
JENKINS_HOME/hudson.tasks.Mailer.xml

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @eran meiri, I created a file called JENKINS_HOME/hudson.tasks.Mailer.xml that looked like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hudson.tasks.Mailer_-DescriptorImpl>
    <smtpHost>my.smtp.host.com</smtpHost>
</hudson.tasks.Mailer_-DescriptorImpl>
```

You can add more properties, but this is all I needed.